# Does it make sense to calculate an option price in future (at t+1)?

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, vega, stress-testing

Often I ask myself whether it makes sense to calculate the price of a Call at `t+1` supposing for example that underlying asset does no move i.e. $S_{t+1} = S_{t}$ and $\sigma$ has changed.

Kind of: $C_{t+1} = f(S_{t}, r, \sigma_{t+1}, K, T)$, $C_{t+2} = f(S_{t}, r, \sigma_{t+2}, K, T)$ etc.

Will that pricing of call in future periods bring any practical value? Where can we use that prices?

I have a few ideas:

- Possibly as basically that calculation is a prediction of `Vega`, as $vega = \frac{C_{t+1}-C_{t}}{\sigma_{t+1}-\sigma_{t}}$ it can be used for hedging (not sure about this statement)
- My professor of trading told me something like "it is used in stress testing" many years ago (what did he talk about?)

Comment: Pricing derivatives at future times is **fundamental** for pricing valuation adjustments (VA) such as Credit VA, Debit VA, Funding VA, etc.

Comment: Overnight risk reports, among other things... I would say: whatever you do in finance, it is important to ask how that changes time-wise and cross-section-wise.

Comment: @stans what do you mean by "cross-section wise"?